# Twitter offline site Concept

Tags: html, twitter, local-storage, application-cache

I want to implement the header as like twitter has. I have observed couple of things like when i click on home link, the url has changed but still page header is not loaded and the content of the page is changed. Can anybody give me some suggestion so that i can put that design on my site?

UPDATE

I have seen this site : [1](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2011/09/26/app-cache-localstorage-survey/), [2](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/09/tech-behind-new-twittercom.html)

I am wondering that how twitter manages offline site. Because I have tried couple of [example](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/how-to-create-offline-html5-web-apps-in-5-easy-steps) for application caching, and i have got warning on my firefox browser about page storing. While I am opening twitter site on firefox this warning dosen't appear. What could be the reason. I have also observe that twitter is using locaStorage first time. What is the concept behind twitter offline site caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cyberfox already mentioned - it's called browser state. The JS-framework BackboneJS implements this method for you: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/.

More specific: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History-start

Answer (score 0):

As Twitter is a mix of good CSS and very much of AJAX, jQuery is probably what you're looking for. (http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Thanks daniel. I am using jQuery in my current app. but i am wondering that how the page in not loaded when the url is changed.

Comment: So to be more specific, the url is known in `document.location`, put together in `document.location.href` or single parts in `document.location.protocol`, `document.location.host`, etc. With this given you can change the url as and refresh it with `document.location.assign()`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want the history methods (`pushState`, `popState`) in HTML5, or the hash-bang operations in HTML4.

Here's a comprehensive overview of the state of the art in history munging, and browser state: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling

...along with a library ([history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)) to help.