# How to use sitemesh effectively in webapplication

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, sitemesh

I implement sitemesh in my java web application but when I click on the next page link that time header and footer again render to the body.

Is there any way to change only the body section of the page?

Like ajax to change boy content in sitemesh and how to implement so header and footer page not render every time.

I read this link http://java.dzone.com/news/ajaxified-body but not able to configure is there any special configuration

u can see twitter.com or facebook.com when user logs in u can see the header panel that can not reload or even reflect when u click on any link. so how this can be achieved? @jayesh

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're clicking on a link that loads a part of the page using AJAX, and Sitemesh decorates that page, which you don't want.

If so, then the answer is in the question. Configure sitemesh so that it doesn't decorate this AJAX request (or all AJAX requests). You could for example make all the AJAX URLs use a common prefix (like ajax), and use the following rule:

```
<mapping path="/ajax*" exclude="true"/>
```

Or you could extend the Sitemesh filter, detect if the request is an AJAX request using the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH request header, and only filter if it's not an ajax request.

Comment: if i do it this way then all process flow at javascript  side and i not able to validate user request that's why i wont to do at server side .

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please clarify your original question. Don't hesitate to join screenshots if necessary.

Comment: u can see https://twitter.com/ or http://www.facebook.com/ when user logs in u can see the header panel that can not reload or even reflect when u click on any link. so how this can be achieve ?

Comment: see this can help u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984868/twitter-offline-site-concept/8985369#8985369

Comment: I don't have any facebook or twitter account, but anyway, you don't have many options. Use frames (but I wouldn't do that: they cause a whole lot of problems), or use AJAX to refresh only some part of the page.

Comment: @Anand Soni this is not problem of offline site Concept or any page cache this is problem with render header and footer at once and swap body content